Unity EditorWindow: "Clip" and "obj" Property Not Selectable use SerializedObject
I'm working with a SerializedObject in Unity 2022 and encountering an issue where the "Clip" and "obj" property cannot be selected for input in the gui. I've provided the relevant code snippet below:
public class Colltorer : EditorWindow
{

    
    string para = "";
    string Cname = "";
    bool face = false;
    bool iscrip = true;
    bool facede = false;
    
    private static Vector2 ScrollPos = Vector2.zero;
    [SerializeField]
    public AnimationClip[] Clip = { };
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject[] obj = { };
    RuntimeAnimatorController runtimeController = null;


    private void OnGUI()
    {


        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        iscrip = GUILayout.Toggle(iscrip, "IS Animation clip?");
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
       
        ScrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(ScrollPos, GUI.skin.box);
        if (iscrip)
        {
            ScriptableObject target = this;
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            GUILayout.Label("Element 0 is for idel clip!!");
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        
            SerializedObject so = new SerializedObject(target);
            SerializedProperty stringsProperty = so.FindProperty("Clip");
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(stringsProperty, true); 
            so.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
        else
        {

              ScriptableObject obsj = this;
              EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
              GUILayout.Label("clip generate!!");
              EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            
              SerializedObject sa = new SerializedObject(obsj);
              SerializedProperty stringsPropertys = sa.FindProperty("obj");
              SerializedProperty stringsPropertyss = sa.FindProperty("ison");
              EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(stringsPropertys, new GUIContent("Game Obj"),true); 
              sa.ApplyModifiedProperties();

 
        }
        

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        runtimeController = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Controller", runtimeController, typeof(RuntimeAnimatorController), true) as RuntimeAnimatorController;

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label("AnimatorController Layer Name");
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        Cname = GUILayout.TextField(Cname);


        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label("Paramitter Name(Type::Int)");
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();


        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        para = GUILayout.TextField(para);


        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        if (iscrip)
            face = GUILayout.Toggle(face, "IS face emote f1-f8!! It will use AnyState duration is 0");
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        if (face)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            facede = GUILayout.Toggle(facede, "GestureLeft for default Parameter face emote :: if used this don't input Parameter");
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            if (facede) para = "GestureLeft";

        }

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
        {
            if (iscrip)
            {
                if (!face) crete();
                else creteface();
            }
            else create_c();
        }

        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }}

Additional Information:

Unity version: 2022.3.6f1
Scripting language: C#
Not have any error message in the console

Question:
What could be causing the "Clip" property to be unselectable in the inspector, and how can I fix this issue?
I've tried the following:

Confirmed the "Clip" property is declared as public and not readonly.
Restarted the Unity editor.

gui image
